# PostgreSQL - best way to store IMEI numbers (not getting rid of lead 0)

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database table called modules:

```
CREATE TABLE module(
  module_id SERIAL,
  imei VARCHAR,
  date TIMESTAMPTZ
);
```

I need to be able to insert actual IMEI into the table. I noticed however that some of the IMEI's are starting with 0, whic seems to be automatically truncated. Here is the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO module (imei, date) VALUES (016748971158668, to_timestamp(1581551700));
```

How can I make sure that the leading 0 won't be removed.

Comment: You should have single-quotes around your IMEI: `INSERT INTO module (imei, date) VALUES ('016748971158668', to_timestamp(1581551700));`

Comment: @richyen, what about when I am passing it as a value in the query like so: pool.query(`INSERT INTO vehicle(custom_id, module_imei, refueled, locked_times, registered) VALUES($1, $2, '0', '0', to_timestamp(${ Date.now() / 1000 })) RETURNING vehicle_id`, [custom_id, module_imei])

Comment: You should be able to put single quotes around `$2`: `'$2'`

Comment: Whatever language and driver you are using should have a way to deal with this.  You should tag what those are so that the right people can read your question.